# Grammatically Correct: Past or Passed

Tags: grammar

What is grammatically correct "without authorization to past" or "without authorization to pass"

Comment: Could you please provide some context? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

*Past* refers to what happened before the present, while *pass* is the action that you take as you move beyond something, so the answer is "without authorization to pass."

Comment: Unless you're a time traveller. ;)